Running a rundeck ansible task on windows server
I try to run an Rundeck ansible task on windows. The following error has occured: "
{"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to create temporary directory. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\", for more error information use -vvv. Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp `\"&& mkdir \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-xxxxxxx `\" && echo ansible-tmp-xxxxxxxx=\"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-xxxxx `\" ), exited with result 1", "unreachable": true}

If i run the same ansible code via CLI everthings works fine. Also the node discovery is working fine in rundeck.
My connection to the windows server is done via SSH. I do not use WinRM.
How can i fix this problem?
This is my "Ansible Playbook Inline Workflow Node Step"
- name: Example from an Ansible Playbook
  hosts: server1
  tasks:
  - win_ping:

My Rundeck project config:
project.ansible-binaries-dir-path=/usr/bin
project.ansible-config-file-path=/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
project.ansible-generate-inventory=true
project.ansible-ssh-auth-type=privateKey
project.ansible-ssh-key-storage-path=keys/project/TestProject/Ansible_Test
project.ansible-ssh-passphrase-option=option.password
project.ansible-ssh-user=ansible
project.ansible-windows-executable=powershell.exe
project.description=
project.disable.executions=false
project.disable.schedule=false
project.execution.history.cleanup.batch=500
project.execution.history.cleanup.enabled=false
project.execution.history.cleanup.retention.days=60
project.execution.history.cleanup.retention.minimum=50
project.execution.history.cleanup.schedule=0 0 0 1/1 \* ? \*
project.jobs.gui.groupExpandLevel=1
project.keep-alive-max-alive-count=5
project.label=
project.later.executions.disable=false
project.later.executions.enable=false
project.later.schedule.disable=false
project.later.schedule.enable=false
project.name=TestProject
project.nodeCache.enabled=true
project.nodeCache.firstLoadSynch=true
project.output.allowUnsanitized=false
project.retry-counter=3
project.ssh-authentication=privateKey
resources.source.1.config.ansible-gather-facts=true
resources.source.1.config.ansible-ignore-errors=true
resources.source.1.config.ansible-inventory=/etc/rundeck/ansible_repo.yml
resources.source.1.config.ansible-ssh-auth-type=privateKey
resources.source.1.config.ansible-ssh-key-storage-path=keys/project/TestProject/Ansible_Test
resources.source.1.config.ansible-ssh-user=ansible
resources.source.1.type=com.batix.rundeck.plugins.AnsibleResourceModelSourceFactory
resources.source.2.type=local
service.FileCopier.default.provider=sshj-scp
service.NodeExecutor.default.provider=com.batix.rundeck.plugins.AnsibleNodeExecutor


Have you checked how the configuration path within the Ci is setup. Also did you try creating a new ansible instance where you changed the tmp path to reflect and match the ansible playbook like the error message is prompting?

If i run another job an linux Server, everthings runs fine
